# How to Convert Data Where Inputs/Features Have Different Shapes to a Dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning

Example raw data where it's a List of Dict:

```
data = [
 {
   input1: 'Hello',
   input2: -100,
   input3: [1, 2, 3],
   target: 1
 },
 ...
]
```

How do I convert this to a TensorFlow dataset using something like **tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()**?

***Alternate Solution***

I've followed this guide: https://keras.io/examples/structured_data/structured_data_classification_from_scratch/

Here it's raw data -> dataframe -> dataset. I have been able to do this by flattening **input3**.

Is this the way I should be doing it?

Because on the official TensorFlow docs, they have an example for multiple inputs:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional#models_with_multiple_inputs_and_outputs

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using ChatGPT. May help someone in the future

**Step 1:**

*Define a function to preprocess the data into a tuple*

```
def preprocess_data(item):
  features = {k: v for k, v in item.items() if k != 'target'}
  label = item['target']

  return features, label
```

**Step 2:**

*Create dataset using *tf.data.Dataset.from_generator**

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: iter(data), 
  output_types={ 'input1': tf.string, 'input2': tf.int32, 'input3': tf.int32,
                 'target': tf.int32 
  } 
  output_shapes=( 
    { 'input1': [], 'input2': [], 'input3': [3], 'target': [] }
  )
```

**Step 3:**

*Call map function your **dataset** passing in the **preprocess_data** function*

```
dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_data)
```